# WebView inside layout which has percentage height except Linearlayout

Tags: android, android-webview, percentage

I want to put my webview implementation into any layout that has a percentage or anything else that makes my webview appear on various screens based on their size. Example, I want the Web display also appear on 30% of the screen. Except Linearlayout and PercentageLayout (obsolete) because I don't want to change xml root. How to achieve this goal?

For example, textview has maxline and with maxline we can also display the text on the screen without changing the xml root.

Answer (score 0):

You can set height to RelativeLayout(Parent of webview) dynamically like this

```
 int heightInDp=300;
 float scale =getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
 int heightInPx = (int) (heightInDp * scale + 0.5f);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,heightInPx);
 rl_parent.setLayoutParams(layout);
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about based on screen size?